# Text to pig latin translator inserts duplicate characters

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I'm creating a c# Windows Forms app to convert English Text to Pig Latin, but the program is inserting the first letter (if it's a consonant) five times in the end, instead of just one.

I was able to insert "way" at the end of the text by using an if statement, that checks if the first letter is a vowel. However, my issue starts when it checks if a word is not a vowel.

```
string[] vowels =  new string[5] { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };     

private void BtnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string TextEnglish = txtEnglish.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
    {
        if (TextEnglish.StartsWith(vowels[i]))
        {
            TextEnglish = TextEnglish.Insert(TextEnglish.Length, "way");
        }
        else if(!TextEnglish.StartsWith(vowels[i]))
        {
            string TextEnglishSubstring = TextEnglish.Substring(0, 1);
            TextEnglish = TextEnglish.Insert(TextEnglish.Length, TextEnglishSubstring);
            TextEnglish = TextEnglish.Insert(TextEnglish.Length, "ay");
        }

        //string substringToInsert = TextEnglish.Substring(0, 1);
        //TextEnglish = TextEnglish.Insert(TextEnglish.Length, "c");
        txtPigLatin.Text = TextEnglish;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Have a look at this article on how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `if (vowels.Contains($"{TextEnglish[0]}")) TextEnglish += "way"; else TextEnglish = TextEnglish.Substring(1) + TextEnglish[0] + "ay";`

Comment: Also, note that you're only comparing to lower-case vowels, but I believe Pig Latin applies to upper-case letters as well.

Comment: Why do `TextEnglish = TextEnglish.Insert(TextEnglish.Length, TextEnglishSubstring)` when `TextEnglish += TextEnglishSubstring` would do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I might recommend that you create a separate method for returning a pig-latin translation, and then call that method from your button click event. This allows for better code re-use and will result in cleaner code.

The problem is that you're looping over all the items in the vowels array and changing the text for each iteration. Instead what you want to do is simply determine if the word starts with a vowel or not. Again, this could be written in another method (more code encapsulation, which means this can also be re-used elsewhere if needed).

Note that I've written the vowels as a `string`, but can treat it as a `char[]` (because that's kind of what strings really are), and the trick here is to see if the array `Contains` the first character of the input string:

```
public static bool BeginsWithAVowel(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return false;
    var vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
    return vowels.Contains(input.Substring(0, 1));
}
```

Now, we can use this method to test our string in our pig latin conversion method:

```
public static string ConvertToPigLatin(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return input;

    if (BeginsWithAVowel(input))
    {
        // Add "way" to the end of the string and return it
        return input + "way";
    }

    // Remove the first character and add it, plus "ay", to the end and return it
    return input.Substring(1) + input.Substring(0, 1) + "ay";
}
```

Now, in the button click event, all we have to do to convert the text is call our method with the original text and then set the `Text` property to the result:

```
private void BtnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPigLatin.Text = ConvertToPigLatin(txtEnglish.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the first character against each possible vowel, and it can't possibly by all of them, and you're running the code to convert once for each vowel checked.

Instead, you should check if it's a vowel first, set a flag, then do your conversion logic. There are a few ways to manage this, here's an example:

```
string TextEnglish = txtEnglish.Text;
bool startsWithVowel = vowels.Any(v => TextEnglish.StartsWith(v));
if(startsWithVowel)
{
    // Do vowel logic
}
else
{
    // Do consonant logic
}
```